# Why is there padding between my first nav and the body?

Tags: html, css

[image]I though the first part of my css would make no padding in the body. This is enough content to explain my problem stackoverflow, please allow me to post my question now.

The CSS:

```
*{ 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

header, nav, section, aside, footer{display: block}

body{
    border: solid red 2px;
}

nav{
    border: solid black 2px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
    <html>     
        <head>             
            <title>redditClone</title>     
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link rel=stylesheet href=redditClone.css></link>       
        </head>     
        <body>
            <nav>my subreddits - dashboard - front - all - random - friends</nav>
            <header>
                <h1>Reddit</h1>
                <nav>theRealAgorist preferences</nav>
            </header>   
            <section></section>
            <aside></aside>
            <footer></footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should share a screenshot of how you’re seeing it. Try using the inspector in your browser to find out what’s causing the gap.

Comment: "I though the first part of my css would make no padding in the body. This is enough content to explain my problem stackoverflow, please allow me to post my question now." Very funny.

Comment: I couldn't see any padding using this code on fiddle. The space between your `nav` and your `header` elements are from the `line-height` of the `h1` tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bcwsU/ no visible padding with chromium

Comment: just use reset.css or normalize.css.

Comment: I added the pic; I'm using chrome.

Comment: It's working in guidos jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any padding in Chrome, FF or IE9, but...

try to change this:

```
header nav section aside footer{display: block}
```

to this:

```
header, nav, section, aside, footer {display: block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
```

you must use commas to select many elements

Comment: Changed it already.. thanks. I updated chrome yesterday and this is how I'm seeing it.